Errors were encountered while processing: android-androresolvd
I am using MXLinux based on Debian 12 (Bookworm)
I did sudo apt install android-*
I got this error at the end of the output:
Errors were encountered while processing:
 android-androresolvd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


I am trying to remove that package sudo apt purge android-androresolvd
but getting an error
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  android-androresolvd*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 37.9 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 407686 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing android-androresolvd (1.3-1+b1) ...
invoke-rc.d: initscript android-androresolvd, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package android-androresolvd (--remove):
 installed android-androresolvd package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 android-androresolvd
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

